# error C3224: 'System::Nullable' : no overloaded generic class takes '1' generic type arguments

Tags: .net, c++-cli, nullable

I'm trying to use `Nullable<bool>` as a tribool in C++/CLI (seen as bool? in C#). I get this odd error message from the following function declaration:

```
static IList<Modification^>^ modifications(double mass,
                                           double tolerance,
                                           Nullable<bool> monoisotopic,
                                           Nullable<bool> approved,
                                           Site site,
                                           Position position,
                                           Classification classification,
                                           Nullable<bool> hidden);
```

I have the proper using statements to bring the types into scope. The error occurs for each use of Nullable:

```
error C3224: 'System::Nullable' : no overloaded generic class takes '1' generic type arguments
```

I also tried `Nullable<System::Boolean>` but get the same error. The error goes away if I use the fully qualified name System::Nullable...but why?!

Comment: Do you have a using _declaration_ or a using _directive_ to bring `System::Nullable<>` into scope? I can't repro with VC++ 2010 SP1 (with a using directive); what version of VC++ are you using?

Comment: @ildjarn: VC++ 2008 SP1. I use this directive:
`using System::Nullable;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different `System::Nullable`s -- [a non-generic one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx) and [a generic one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). Your using declaration brings into scope the former, when it is the latter that you actually want to use.

Unfortunately, it is a limitation of C++/CLI that one cannot use a using declaration to bring a generic type into scope when there exists another non-generic type with the same name. Your only real options here are to fully qualify the type name or to use a using *directive* instead of a using declaration (i.e., `using namespace System;`).